# Thread related issues and debugging them

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, operating-system

This is my follow up to the previous post on memory management issues. The following are the issues I know.

1)data races (atomicity violations and data corruption)

2)ordering problems

3)misusing of locks leading to dead locks

4)heisenbugs

Any other issues with multi threading ? How to solve them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric's list of four issues is pretty much spot on.  But debugging these issues is tough.

For deadlock, I've always favored "leveled locks".  Essentially you give each type of lock a level number.  And then require that a thread aquire locks that are monotonic.

To do leveled locks, you can declare a structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
   os_mutex actual_lock;
   int level;
   my_lock *prev_lock_in_thread;
} my_lock_struct;

static __tls my_lock_struct *last_lock_in_thread;

void my_lock_aquire(int level, *my_lock_struct lock) {
    if (last_lock_in_thread != NULL) assert(last_lock_in_thread->level < level)
    os_lock_acquire(lock->actual_lock)
    lock->level = level
    lock->prev_lock_in_thread = last_lock_in_thread
    last_lock_in_thread = lock
}
```

What's cool about leveled locks is the possibility of deadlock causes an assertion.  And with some extra magic with **FUNC** and **LINE** you know exactly what badness your thread did.

For data races and lack of synchronization, the current situation is pretty poor.  There are static tools that try to identify issues.  But false positives are high.

The company I work for ( http://www.corensic.com ) has a new product called Jinx that actively looks for cases where race conditions can be exposed.  This is done by using virtualization technology to control the interleaving of threads on the various CPUs and zooming in on communication between CPUs.

Check it out.  You probably have a few more days to download the Beta for free.

Jinx is particularly good at finding bugs in lock free data structures.  It also does very well at finding other race conditions.  What's cool is that there are no false positives.  If your code testing gets close to a race condition, Jinx helps the code go down the bad path.  But if the bad path doesn't exist, you won't be given false warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no good pill that helps automatically solve most/all threading issues. Even unit tests that work so well on single-threaded pieces of code may never detect an extremely subtle race condition.

One thing that will help is keeping the thread-interaction data encapsulated in objects. The smaller the interface/scope of the object, the easier it will be to detect errors in review (and possibly testing, but race conditions can be a pain to detect in test cases). By keeping a simple interface that can be used, clients that use the interface will also be correct just by default. By building up a bigger system from lots of smaller pieces (only a handful of which actually do thread-interaction), you can go a long way towards averting threading errors in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The four most common problems with theading are

1-Deadlock
2-Livelock
3-Race Conditions
4-Starvation

Comment: All of these problems can be solved with semaphores (locks). You need to carefully understand what you are doing first. Try not to over do it with threads, they are a tool to help your program do stuff, not some magical trick you need to put all over the place

Answer (score 1):

> How to solve [issues with multi threading]?

A good way to "debug" MT applications is through logging. A good logging library with extensive filtering options makes it easier. Of course, logging itself influences the timing, so you still can have "heisenbugs", but it's much less likely than when you're actuall breaking into the debugger.

Prepare and plan for that. Include a good logging facility into your application from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Make your threads as simple as possible.

Try not to use global variables.  Global constants (actual constants that never change) is fine.  When you do need to use global or shared variables you need to protect them with some type of mutex/lock (semaphore, monitor, ...).

Make sure that you actually understand what how your mutexes work.  There are a few different implementations which can work differently.

Try to organize your code so that the critical sections (places where you hold some type of lock(s) ) are as quick as possible.  Be aware that some functions may block (sleep or wait on something and keep the OS from allowing that thread to continue running for some time).  Do not use these while holding any locks (unless absolutely necessary or during debugging as it can sometimes show other bugs).

Try to understand what more threads actually does for you.  Blindly throwing more threads at a problem is very often going to make things worse.  Different threads compete for the CPU and for locks.

Deadlock avoidance requires planning.  Try to avoid having to acquire more than one lock at a time.  If this is unavoidable decide on an ordering you will use to acquire and release the locks for all threads.  Make sure you know what deadlock really means.

Debugging multi-threaded or distributed applications is difficult.  If you can do most of the debugging in a single threaded environment (maybe even just forcing other threads to sleep) then you can try to eliminate non-threading centric bugs before jumping into multi-threaded debugging.

Always think about what the other threads might be up to.  Comment this in your code.  If you are doing something a certain way because you know that at that time no other thread should be accessing a certain resource write a big comment saying so.

You may want to wrap calls to mutex locks/unlocks in other functions like:

int my_lock_get(lock_type lock, const char * file, unsigned line, const char * msg) {

```
 thread_id_type me = this_thread();

 logf("%u\t%s (%u)\t%s:%u\t%s\t%s\n", time_now(), thread_name(me), me, "get", msg);

 lock_get(lock);

 logf("%u\t%s (%u)\t%s:%u\t%s\t%s\n", time_now(), thread_name(me), me, "in", msg);
```

}

And a similar version for unlock.  Note, the functions and types used in this are all made up and not overly based on any one API.

Using something like this you can come back if there is an error and use a perl script or something like it to run queries on your logs to examine where things went wrong (matching up locks and unlocks, for instance).

Note that your print or logging functionality may need to have locks around it as well.  Many libraries already have this built in, but not all do.  These locks need to not use the printing version of the lock_[get|release] functions or you'll have infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Beware of global variables even if
   they are `const`, in particular in
   C++. Only POD that are statically
   initialized "à la" C are good here.
   As soon as a run-time constructor
   comes into play, be extremely
   careful. AFAIR initialization order
   of variables with static linkage that are in
   different compilation units are
   called in an undefined order. Maybe
   C++ classes that initialize all
   their members properly and have an
   empty function body, could be ok
   nowadays, but I once had a bad
   experience with that, too.

   This is one of the reason why on the
   POSIX side `pthread_mutex_t` is much
   easier to program than `sem_t`: it
   has a static initializer
   `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.
2. Keep critical sections as short as
   possible, for two reasons: it might
   be more efficient at the end, but
   more importantly it is easier to
   maintain and to debug.

   A critical section should never be
   longer that a screen, including the
   locking and unlocking that is needed
   to protect it, and including the
   comments and assertions that help
   the reader to understand what is
   happening.

   Start implementing critical sections
   very rigidly maybe with one global
   lock for them all, and relax the
   constraints afterwards.
3. Logging might is difficult if many
   threads start to write at the same
   time. If every thread does a
   reasonable amount of work try to
   have them each write a file of their
   own, such that they don't interlock
   each other.

   But beware, logging changes behavior
   of code. This can be bad when bugs
   disappear, or beneficial when bugs
   appear that you otherwise wouldn't
   have noticed.

   To make a post-mortem analysis of
   such a mess you have to have
   accurate timestamps on each line
   such that all the files can be
   merged and give you a coherent view
   of the execution.

Answer (score 1):

-> Add priority inversion to that list.

As another poster eluded to, log files are wonderful things.  For deadlocks, using a `LogLock` instead of a `Lock` can help pinpoint when you entities stop working.  That is, once you know you've got a deadlock, the log will tell you when and where locks were instantiated and released.  This can be enormously helpful in tracking these things down.

I've found that race conditions when using an Actor model following the same message->confirm->confirm received style seem to disappear.  That said, YMMV.